# What are some good resources for understanding disassembly dumps from `objdump`?

Tags: x86, disassembly, objdump

I would like to know where I can get started understanding disassembly in this format. I am familiar with OllyDbg from back in my windows days but this is a bit different, and would like to get the semantics down.
Example of part of what I'm talking about `objdump -d loops`:

```
080483b4 <main>:
 80483b4:   55                      push   %ebp
 80483b5:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80483b7:   83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
 80483ba:   c7 45 f8 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x8(%ebp)
 80483c1:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%ebp)
 80483c8:   eb 11                   jmp    80483db <main+0x27>
 80483ca:   83 45 f8 01             addl   $0x1,-0x8(%ebp)
 80483ce:   81 7d f8 f4 01 00 00    cmpl   $0x1f4,-0x8(%ebp)
 80483d5:   75 f3                   jne    80483ca <main+0x16>
 80483d7:   83 45 fc 01             addl   $0x1,-0x4(%ebp)
 80483db:   81 7d fc f4 01 00 00    cmpl   $0x1f4,-0x4(%ebp)
 80483e2:   75 ea                   jne    80483ce <main+0x1a>
 80483e4:   c9                      leave  
 80483e5:   c3                      ret
```

Thank you

Comment: FYI: you can do use `-m i386:intel` or `-m i386:x86-64:intel` respecetively to get intel syntax on your output from objdump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out more about the AT&T x86 assembly language syntax, for example, [here](http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/linasm.html).